# C# array help for visual studio reading from arduino

Tags: visual-studio-2015, arduino

I have been searching for help on this for a couple of days. I just can't find an answer to my problem. My code seems right but I keep getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error.

This is the basics of my code. The Arduino reads three temp sensors and sends them to visual studio separated by a space. I only need two of them at a time depending on what state my mode variable is in. There should only be an array of three (data sent should look like 70 68 86) I am calling for each 0-2 from the array but I keep getting the error.

I have gone over the code and it looks right to me, but obviously something is wrong. any help to see what I am overlooking would be great.

here is the C# code - it is running from a VS tick event every 2.7 seconds

```
        private void TempSensor_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CTemp = 15;
            ac_control = CTemp;
            string temp_rx;
            Console.WriteLine("start of tick event before run_arduino " + ac_control);
            run_arduino();
            temp_rx = port.ReadExisting();
            string cabTemp = temp_rx.ToString();

            string[] tempread = cabTemp.Split(' ');
                string a = tempread[0]; //cabin temp
                string b = tempread[1]; //vent temp
                string c = tempread[2]; //heat vent temp

            if ((M == 6) || (M == 7))
            {
                cabinLabel.Text = a + "°F";
                ventLabel.Text = c + "°F";
            }
            else
            {
                cabinLabel.Text = a + "°F";
                ventLabel.Text = b + "°F";
            }

        }
```

and here is the code the Arduino is running - the tick event sends val=15 through serial to run this part of the if statement.

```
    else if (val == 15)
      {
        float ctemp = dht.readTemperature();
        float vtemp = dht1.readTemperature();  
        float htemp = dht2.readTemperature();

        // change celsius to fahrrnheit
        ctemp = ctemp * 1.8 + 32;
        vtemp = vtemp * 1.8 + 32;
        htemp = htemp * 1.8 + 32;

          Serial.print(ctemp,0);
          Serial.print(" ");
          Serial.print(vtemp,0);
          Serial.print(" ");
          Serial.print(htemp,0);

      }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you also show port.ReadExisting() ?

Comment: I think that maybe you are not getting back the string you think you are, leading to tempread not being the array you think it is.  Double check the value of `cabTemp` before doing your split.

Comment: didn't think about that, I will try it and see what I am getting from the serial port. This is where I think I am getting the wrong reading

Comment: You have nothing that would prevent you from receiving partial (`7`, `70 6`) or even multiple measurements (`70 68 8670 68 86`).

Comment: ok, took jespers advice and added message boxes to show capTemp and it comes back correct (78 83 67) - then added one for each variable after and I get correct readings (78) (83) & (67). but still getting error "Index was outside the bounds of the array" the rest of message says " Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately" - I added this just in case it would help identify something else for anyone. Clicking continue - app runs normally.